# Most common applications of the C# 4.0 dynamic type

Tags: dynamic, c#-4.0, dynamic-language-runtime

Now that people have been using C# 4.0 for a while I thought I'd see how people were most often using the type 'dynamic' and why has this helped them solve their problem better than they may have done previously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example when using reflection.

Example, something like this:

```
object calc = GetCalculator();
Type calcType = calc.GetType();
object res = calcType.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, new object[] { 10, 20 });
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(res);
```

would than become:

```
dynamic calc = GetCalculator();
int sum = calc.Add(10, 20);
```

That's a big improvement I think.

But there are more subjects where this can come in handy. For instance when working with COM interop objects this could come in handy, look at:
http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/42590

Answer (score 2):

It's also used when embedding dynamic languages such as IronPython/IronRuby to allow loading types defined in external source files, and accessing them more directly in C#